# Usage of "could" showing general ability in past

Tags: modal-verbs, could

For example, I want to tell someone that earlier it was possible to send telegrams through post offices. (Past ability of post office to send telegrams, which is not in service now.) So which of the usage of *could* can be used to tell the same out of two below options:

> 1. The telegrams **could be** sent through Post offices in 1890.
> 2. The telegrams **could have been** sent through post offices in 1890.

Comment: The first is neater, but neither is incorrect.  You could also say *"It was possible to send a telegram through the post office in 1890."* and *etc.*.

Comment: That is besides the point but @PhilSweet

Comment: Everyone on this page is wrong. Because nobody on this page has actually read your question. I apologize for that. The correct answer is as follows: Neither version works. Version 1 will work if you drop the *the* before *telegrams*. Version 2 definitely does not fit your meaning at all, with or without the *the*.

Comment: Oh, and there is definitely no need whatsoever to capitalize *post offices*. You actually got it right at the very start: "it was possible to send telegrams through post offices". Just go ahead and use that. That is fine in every respect.